# Growing foetus in another woman's womb

Tags: obstetrics, fetus, frozen-freeze, surrogacy

If you have a medical issue and are unable to carry a baby, can you have the fetus taken out of you and grown in another woman's womb? Or could you freeze it?

I'm thinking of a medical issue like severe chronic pain or cancer that requires significant medical intervention that may harm the baby's growth inside the mother's body.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently no, but there is work in progress that will allow extremely premature babies to be grown in artificial uteri. It has so far worked well for baby goats.

https://www.theatlantic.com/health/archive/2017/04/preemies-floating-in-fluid-filled-bags/524181/

Answer (score 2):

***Taking a partly developed foetus out of the mother?*** This is currently not an available method.
However, there are methods out there for the problems you described:

### Three-parent baby

One method [allowed in the UK](http://www.bbc.com/news/health-31069173) is called a "*three-parent baby*" and the following [guardian article](https://www.theguardian.com/science/2015/feb/02/three-parent-babies-explained) explains it fairly well:

> The procedure replaces a small amount of faulty DNA in a mother’s egg with healthy DNA from a second woman, so that the baby would inherit genes from two mothers and one father. The idea is to prevent certain genetic diseases being passed on to children.

[image: BBC Graphic Method 1]
[image: BBC Graphic Method 2]
[Image Credit: [BBC Article](http://www.bbc.com/news/magazine-28986843)]      *Click Images for full resolution!*

### Gestational Surrogacy

> Host (or gestational) surrogacy is when IVF (in-vitro fertilisation) is used, either with the eggs of the intended mother, or with donor eggs.  The surrogate therefore does not use her own eggs, and is **genetically unrelated to the baby**. It is physically more complicated and considerably more expensive than straight surrogacy, (although many IPs can have some costs covered by the NHS) and always takes place in a fertility clinic.

Further reading:

- HFEA UK about [Surrogacy](http://www.hfea.gov.uk/fertility-treatment-options-surrogacy.html)
- PubMed Article about [legal and ethical aspects](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3531011/)
- Illinois Department of Health about [Surrogacy](http://dph.illinois.gov/topics-services/birth-death-other-records/birth-records/surrogacy)

Answer (score 1):

No, first you should go throw an [IVF process](https://www.mayoclinic.org/tests-procedures/in-vitro-fertilization/about/pac-20384716) (egg retrieval process and a fertilization by sperm in a lab). Once the embryos are created, after 3 or 5 days they can be transferred to a gestational carrier who will carry the baby until the birth. This process is called [gestational surrogacy](https://www.mysurrogatemom.com/what-is-surrogacy-meaning/). In gestational surrogacy, the surrogate is not genetically linked to the baby, as the embryos are created using the intended mother eggs.

There is a second type of surrogacy, it's called [traditional surrogacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surrogacy#Traditional_surrogacy). In this surrogacy form, the surrogate mother provides her eggs and fertilization is done through a [Intrauterine insemination (IUI) process](http://americanpregnancy.org/infertility/intrauterine-insemination)

Comment: +1 for pointing out the traditional surrogacy method